# Is it legal in Spain for a male airport security guard to ask you to lift up your blouse and swab your bare stomach?

Tags: legal, airport-security, spain

I was randomly picked for a paper swab at Bilbao airport. I was asked to come behind a screen with a male security guard, although I am a single female. He asked me to lift up my blouse and proceeded to swab my bare stomach and also swabbed my expensive dress in my suitcase. Is it actually legal to ask me to lift up my blouse, as I find it a bit indecent?

I would also like to know what is on the paper, as I started to itch afterwards.

Comment: It is legal. It is just not appropriate however there is no issue about legality, at least not in Spain. Maybe in the Islamic countries it is illegal.

Comment: I don’t know for sure but I’d imagine you could politely ask for a female security guard instead

Comment: In Canada you have the right to have a person of your sex perform this sort of procedure, but you will be asked and not automatically offered, as it adds time to the endeavour.

Comment: Bilbao is not in Canada.

Comment: @WGroleau the question is posed in general terms, however.

Comment: Why would you consider someone doing their job by brushing a piece of tissue paper against your skin indecent? Now, if they were doing a full rectal exam and vaginal swap maybe, but your belly?

Comment: I'm glad I found this question because i also experienced something similar. In December 2019, I was returning from to the US from Spain, and a female security officer informed me after going through the metal detector that i need to follow her. She took me to a more private area, but still in the site of others, and handed me over to a male security officer. (I am female.) He searched my bag, and then he swabbed phone, laptop, hands, and shoes. Then, he went behind me and asked me to lift up my shirt in the back. At first, I had no idea why he was asking me to lift my top, and I was shocked,

Comment: This is pretty common and completely fine give that it is not an intimate area and the guard is not actually touching you or patting you. I realize that people have different levels of comfort but the swab touching you has no gender. They are now performing temperature checks on people and it would slow down if you had to ask for a different person based on gender when only the thermometer is in contact with your skip for a second

Comment: @user56513 your comment is absolutely absurd. This would be headlines material if they performed a similar search of a burqua clad islamic women in Spain or for that matter any where in Europe. Would that make EU, the Islamic Union of European Nations? There really is no need to introduce your bigotry into a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Itai  there's a difference between a man taking a woman's temperature and a man lifting up a woman's top and touch her body with a swab. Besides for that, it won't really slow everyone down if they bring a female to swab one woman's waist, and you can't compare that to taking people's temperature, where every person is having their temperature taken.

Comment: What's appropriate or feels like an invasion depends strongly on culture. Is it legal/appropriate is a valid question, yes/it's not seen as problematic in Spain is also a valid answer. But all the comments treating this as an absolute truth, dictating how the OP should feel or professing that they cannot possibly imagine anybody would have an issue with this are not helpful, could we stop it please?

Comment: @TooTea Yes, many women (and probably some men) are sensitive to the gender of medical practitioners and specifically seek one of their preferred gender, either as a GP or for specialities like O&G. Is that really so difficult to understand?

Comment: @Relaxed No, it's not difficult to understand. I'm sorry if my question came across as rhetorical or as an expression of disbelief. I have deleted it now.

Comment: @nikhil You are speaking very ignorantly. Where is the bigotry? Do you know what religion I practice?

Answer (score 11):

> Is it actually legal to ask me to lift up my blouse, as I find it a bit indecent?

Yes, its "legal" because **it is not against the law.** The security personnel have asked me to remove shoes, belt, lift up my shirt, turn over my pant waist, all in the name of security and all in the public area.

I guess the question in your mind is if it is okay for a male to do that for a female. In many airports, you can ask for a person of the same gender to screen you in private, or have one present while screened. However, as mentioned in the comments this has to be requested and even then it may not be practical as there may not be someone available; which may add to a delay for you.

As for the reaction on your skin, simply apply any topical allergy cream or ointment. It is likely a reaction against the fiberglass strands in the swab. If the rash persists or it becomes itchy, consult a medical professional.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, [aena](http://www.aena.es/en/bilbao-airport/index.html), the Spanish airport authority/operator, provides little guidance on you first question.

However, if you travel to the US, Canada or Australia, you can always ask for a same gender screener and they have to comply.

The most common swabs are Teflon coated fiberglass.  See: [Sample Traps](https://www.dsadetection.com/sample-traps-100ct.html).

You may have a simply allergy to one of those.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81202/discussion-on-answer-by-johns-305-is-it-legal-for-a-male-airport-security-guard).

Answer (score 0):

First, for your information, they may not give you a hard time if you just lift your shirt a little without actually revealing skin. I realized this when I was traveling from Germany and I was asked to lift my shirt. I was wearing a dress with cardigan on top. I lifted my cardigan a little, and the agent didn't seem to mind that my skin was covered with my dress. From my experience, it seems to be common in Europe to be asked to lift your top so they can swab your stomach and waist area, though sometimes they do it on top of the clothing.

Regarding opposite genders, it appears to be legal in Spain, as well as most European countries. I even recall seeing people getting patted down by the opposite gender in Europe. I personally was swabbed my a male agent (I am female) on one of my trips to Europe. In the United States, however, if security need contact with your body, it will be done by someone of your gender.